# Custom taxonomy only gets saved in quick edit

Tags: custom-taxonomy, save-post

I have set up 2 custom taxonomies for my posts: `verdicts` and `sponsors`.

The problem is that `sponsors` do not get saved when publishing a post, it can only get saved when I check it in quick edit mode.

The code for my custom taxonomy is pretty basic, as you can see below.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks!

```
<?php 
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_sponsors() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Sponsors', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        // the rest of labels
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'              => 'sponsor',
        'with_front'        => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
    );
    $args2 = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud'     => false,
        'query_var'         => 'sponsor',
        'rewrite'           => $rewrite,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'sponsor', array( 'post' ), $args2 );
}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_sponsors', 0 );
```

Comment: The code you've posted does not have anything to do with saving posts. Show us `add_action(  'save_post', 'your_function_name' );` part.

Comment: I have not created one since I am not using custom posts, only custom taxonomies for the native posts ... Was I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I was inattentive on post type. I can't reproduce the problem, your code works for me flawlessly. Try the following. Flush rewrite rules (Settings → Permalinks → Save) and see if it helps. If not, change `init` action priority to something different from `0`, let's say 10.

Comment: Thanks for this but it did not work. I have also tried saving with all of the plugins deactivated. It works fine when checking that taxonomy in quick-edit mode. This is so weird.